# How to open settings page in the ios simulator and change the app setting using Appium

Tags: appium, webdriver-io

How to open settings page in the ios simulator and go to my app setting and change the environment using Appium

[image]

I am not able to find any documentation how to do this in webdriverio and appium

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can open preferences using Appium [`activateApp`](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/app/activate-app/) method:

```java
driver.activateApp("com.apple.Preferences");
```

Then just like with any other screen, search for locators and interact with them using standard methods.

Comment: and if i need to change anything in the setting, i will have to use the normal automation script, correct? just like automating any feature

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to use instead the driver.executeScript function with mobile commands.
You can automate a lot without the need to navigate in the ios settings app.

This is the [Appium Documentation](https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/mobile-command/) and you can find all commands [here](https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver#platform-specific-extensions).

Example for disabling FaceId in Java for the current app you want to automate:

```
driver.executeScript("mobile:enrollBiometric", ImmutableMap.of("isEnabled", false));
```