# How can i set Dark/Light mode on iOS using appium

Tags: appium, appium-ios

I have tried the below code block in @Before and nothing happens the test passed with no error but device mode did not change to dark

```html
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("mobile:setAppearance", "{style: 'dark'}");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command is an alias to the `xcrun simctl ui` command which is only applicable to the simulators.

The only way to do this on a real device is to open **Settings** -> **Display & Brightness** and click on Dark mode. You can see some details on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61881382/how-to-open-settings-page-in-the-ios-simulator-and-change-the-app-setting-using/61884566#61884566)